# UITextView keyboard is taking 2 taps to open.

Tags: swift, keyboard, uitextview, xcode7

I have a UITextView with a label over it as a placeholder. When the user taps on the UITextView the label disappears but for the keyboard to appear it takes another 2 taps. When I remove the tap gesture that hides the label the keyboard works perfectly. Here is my code any ideas as to what the problem is???

```
var tapTerm:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()



 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bioTextfield.delegate = self



    tapTerm = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapTextView:")
    // bioPlaceholderLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapTerm)
    bioTextfield.addGestureRecognizer(tapTerm)
        }


func tapTextView(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // hide placeholder label text
    bioPlaceholderLabel.text = ""

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



// when user touches outside the keyboard close the keyboard


 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


    self.view.endEditing(true)

}

// when user presses the return button close the keyboard

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Easier way, you should use this custom UITextView (with place holder): [KMPlaceholderTextView](https://github.com/MoZhouqi/KMPlaceholderTextView). I'm using, so great.

Comment: Hi @t4nhpt thanks for the link I have decided to try implement this placeholder. It is involving a lot more code on my VC with what i'm using, pity I couldn't figure out the label way. Anyway thanks!